# Does inverse square law indicate beam angle of radiation source?

Tags: radiation, units

I was told that the radiation intensity from a particular X-ray machine falls in half every 4 feet.  I think this should tell us something about the angle of the beam from the machine.  I use trigonometry to restate the assertion as follows:

Radiation is emitted at some angle *θ* producing a cone whose diameter grows by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ every 4 feet.  Therefore: I think $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4})$.

The problem I see is that the term $\sqrt{2}$ is unitless, so this would be taking the arctan of inverse feet, not of a unitless ratio.  (And since angles aren't in units of inverse-length the statement appears to be meaningless; "4" is not anchored to anything – it could just as well be units of meters or lightyears.)

What am I missing here?  The initial statement seems valid, and I don't see how it can be true of more than one beam angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the radiation intensity from a particular X-ray machine falls in half every $4$ feet

This is the important part. After $4$ feet you have half the original intensity. After $4$ more feet, you have half of that, or $1/4$ of the original intensity. After $4$ more, $1/8$. And so on.

This is exponential decay

$$I = I_0 \cdot 2^{-x/(4 ft)}$$

Try it out with x = 0 ft, 4 ft, 8 ft, etc.

Exponential decay is common when light is absorbed. The x-rays are not spreading out. They do not travel far in air or whatever is around the machine.

Comment: Why did you divide the power by 4 ft rather than the whole 2^a expression by that?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse square law works from a radius point. If you consider 4 foot to be the initial radius then two times the radius would not be Half the radiation, it would be 1/4 the radiation. Three times the radius would be 1/9 the radiation and four times the radius would be 1/16.

Comment: Ah ha: The statement "radiation falls in half over four feet" can only be true for one four-foot segment orthogonal to the radiation.  Which means that the $\sqrt{2}$ in my example must be in units of feet, and the underling beam has an angle of about 10 degrees.